# GetStream.io posts like in facebook

Tags: flutter, kotlin, getstream-io

Ok, I have a feed with a lot of activities.

The user can post an activity.

**I want something facebook like... So other users can like that post and can write answers to it. How can I do that?**

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are asking about Reactions, which can be implemented using the API. Reactions can be "likes" or "comments" etc, and can include text and images. Read more about them here
https://getstream.io/docs/reactions_introduction/?language=js